# GPS accuracy for blind person O&M

Tags: gps, accuracy, assisted-gps, gpstools, gps-track-editor

I would like to be able to use GPS on my phone, in conjunction with an app, to enable O&M (Orientation and Mobility) support, on my device.

I want the app to tell a blind person walking along a rural carless path by a silent river when they are deciding from the path.

The path is mostly straight, with some bends. I want to know whether, on a clear day, the GPS can detect displacements of two meters. If not, what is the displacement accuracy if GPS.

Comment: With DGPS correction (WAAS/EGNOS) 1-3m possible in rural areas, but not under trees.

Comment: Affordable RTK (Real-Time Kinematics) GPS for sub metre precision https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/reach-first-affordable-rtk-gps-receiver#/ ($570.00)

Comment: Do these use different technologies than standard GPS? If the signal is different, why does it cost more to use it? Do these technologies user proprietary signals or something? Thanks.